# Why is there a negative source voltage when the MOSFET is off in this buck converter?

Tags: buck, voltage-source

[image: Vs]

[image: This is my circuit]

This is the voltage source. As you can see, when there is a turn-off phase, I have a negative source. Why?

Comment: Hello there! What is L1 current? What is D1 forward voltage?

Comment: Hello! IL1 = 10 A, Vfdiode = 0.57. For sure is related to diode, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why is there a negative source voltage when mosfet is off?*

It's an asynchronous buck converter and, when the MOSFET turns off (goes open-circuit), the inductor current keeps flowing and forward biases the diode: -

[image]

That's the whole point of the inductor and the diode; it transfers energy from the inductor to the output capacitor. It's absolutely normal operation for this type of converter.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @SirU if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.